# is $a = \{a\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Relatedly, is $\{a\} = a$, $\emptyset$ and that's why $a \ne \{a\}$?
The question given to me is if $A, B$ & $C$ are three sets where $A$ is an element $B, B$ is a subset of $C$, is $A$ then a subset of $C$?

Say $A = \{x\}$

$B = \{\{x\}, y, z\}$

$C = \{\{x\}, y, z, g\}$

I'm guessing $A$ is not a subset of $C$ bc the **element** in $A$ is $x$ whereas the **element** in $C$ is $\{x\}$, which cannot be a subset of itself, therefore all elements of $A$ are not elements of $C$, right?
Also because the list of subsets in the case of $C$ would be {{x}}, {y}, {z}, {g}, { } and so on.

Comment: Your guess is right - A is not a subset of C and $x \ne \{x\}$.

Comment: A book ($a$) is not the same thing as a bag containing a book ($\{ a \}$).

Comment: If indeed $\{a\}=a$ then $a\in a$. This leads to a contradiction to the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#2._Axiom_of_regularity_(also_called_the_axiom_of_foundation)).

Comment: The statement "$\{a\}=a,\emptyset$" makes no sense. A set can *always* be written with curly braces $\{\}$. The empty set is $\emptyset=\{\}$. The set $\{a\}$ is a set with one element. The reason $\{a\}$ is not equal to $a$ is because one is a set and the other is (presumably) not.

Comment: @ElliotG In set theory *every* object is a set.

Comment: @drhab yes but I don't think that is useful for someone learning set notation for the first time

Comment: @ElliotG Well, IMV the sooner the better. But let us not further argue about it. Cheers.

Comment: Whatever $A, B, C$, $$A\in B,B\subset C\implies A\in C.$$

Answer (score 1):

> "The question given to me is if $A, B$ & $C$ are three sets where $A$ is an element $B, B$ is a subset of $C$, is $A$ then a subset of $C$?"

---

Let it be that indeed $A\in B$ and $B\subseteq C$.

Now we wonder: do we have $A\subseteq C$?

The answer is: **not in general**.

For instance if $B=\{A\}=C$ then the conditions are satisfied but we cannot conclude that $A\subseteq\{A\}$.

To see this let it be that $A$ contains an element $x$ that satisfies $x\neq A$.

Then we have $x\in A$ and *not* $x\in\{A\}$ and this tells us exactly that $A$ is *not* a subset of $\{A\}$.

---

Another question is: is it *possible* that $A\subseteq C$?

The answer on that is: **yes**.

For instance let $B=\{A\}$ again and now let $C=\{A\}\cup A$.

Then it is obvious that we have $A\subseteq C$.

---

For the question in the title see my comment on your question.

Answer (score 0):

$P$ is a subset of $Q$ whenever for each $p\in P \implies p\in Q $

Now, as you assume , $A = \{x\}$
$B = \{\{x\}, y, z\}$
$C = \{\{x\}, y, z, g\}$,
From these, clearly $A$ is not subset of $B$ as well as of $C$ , since, the element $x$ doesn't belong in any of $B$ and $C$.

Here, the main thing, if $A, B$ & $C$ are three sets where $A$ is an element $B, B$ is a subset of $C$, is $A$ then a subset of $C$? And answer of this question can be true!

Just taking a little change to assump sets,,,
$A = \{x\}$
$B = \{\{x\}, y, z\}$
$C = \{\{x\}, y, z, x\}$

Clearly, here, $A$ is a subset as well as element of $C$.

Answer (score 0):

$A =\{x\}$ is indeed an element of $B=\{\{x\}, y,z\}$ "on inspection", as $B$ has 3 elements: $y$,$z$ and $\{x\}=A$. $y,z$ themselves stand for some sets, and $x$ too.

$B$ is a subset of $C = \{\{x\},y,z,g\}$, because every element of $B$ (which I just listed, there are three) is *also* an element of $B$. So in particular $A \in C$ as well.

$A$ is not a subset of $C$ as the only element of $A$ is $x$ and the set $x$ is **not** an element of $C$ ($g,y,z$ must all be distinct of course, this is implicit in the choice of notation) If we *had* chosen $g=x$ in the notation, then we do have $A \subseteq C$. But we have $g \neq x$ instead.

We know that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq C$ does imply $A \subseteq C$, but here we just have $A \in B$, $B \subseteq C$ (and so) $A \in C$, not $A \subseteq C$.